# function not printing out link

Tags: php, mysql

Hopefully someone can spot my error, but the link is not getting printed out.

**Function:**

```
function getGames($console) {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM `games` WHERE `console` = ? ORDER BY `name` ASC';
    $params = array($console);
    $results = dataQuery($query,$params);
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        echo '<td style="float: left;padding-left: 5px;>';
        echo '<a href="?page=ladders/game&id='.$result['id'].'" title="'.$result['name'].'">';
        echo '<img src="images/games/'.$result['image'].'" alt="'.$result['name'].'" width="100px" height="100px" />';
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</td>';
    }
}
```

It prints out the image fine but its not clickable, which means there's some kind of mess-up in the `<a href` part. It looks correct to me though.

Comment: What does the HTML output look like? Have you done any debugging?

Comment: This line is missing an end quote: `echo '<td style="float: left;padding-left: 5px;>';`

Comment: You're missing a quote " at the end of the td style.

Comment: well smoked too much herb this morning i guess haha. knew it was an error by me. thanks that fixed it lol

Comment: Naw, some else can if they want, it's just typographical so it's actually considered *Off Topic*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing double quote at `<td style="float: left;padding-left: 5px;>`

```
function getGames($console) {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM `games` WHERE `console` = ? ORDER BY `name` ASC';
    $params = array($console);
    $results = dataQuery($query,$params);
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        echo '<td style="float: left;padding-left: 5px;">';
        echo '<a href="?page=ladders/game&id='.$result['id'].'" title="'.$result['name'].'">';
        echo '<img src="images/games/'.$result['image'].'" alt="'.$result['name'].'" width="100px" height="100px" />';
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</td>';
    }
}
```